# Online C++ compiler, with an API, ability to download .exe

Tags: web-apps, c++, api

Are there any online services that allow generating an executable file (`.exe`) from C++ code? Additionally, it is important for me that this service has an API.

I need to send a request to an API with C++ code and receive a return `.exe` file.

I have tried to find such services but have not been successful so far.

Comment: Compiling on your machine is obviously not what you want.  Why ?  This may help in the solution.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @RohitGupta I want to write a program that will create an .exe from source code even if no C++ compilers are installed on the computer

Comment: You could file an issue in [compiler-explorer](https://github.com/compiler-explorer/compiler-explorer) and ask for this feature. Maybe there is something like this already in Compiler Explorer although I would suspect that they don't want to have an API to make it harder to misuse their limited resources.